# Broken point process

Tags: python, random

I'm generating points `(x, y, radius)` from a Poisson point process using `numpy.random.poission` distribution.

Here's my implementation:

```
import numpy as np


def index_to_coordinates(size, point):
    quotient, x = divmod(point, size)
    z, y = divmod(quotient, size)
    return x, y, z


def coordinates_to_index(size, x, y, z):
    return x + y * size + z * size ** 2


def poisson_point_process(rate, area):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    point = 0
    while point <= area:
        # w = int(-np.log(rng.uniform(0, 1)) * rate)
        w = rng.poisson(rate)
        point += w
        yield point
```

Most of the time seams to work fine,

```
size = 256
radii = 7
expected_count = 32
area = size * size * radii - 1  # 458751
rate = area // expected_count  # 14335
```

[image]

but with certain combination it breaks, and points form lines in the `x` direction (`y` coordinates are stripey),
i.g.

```
size = 256
radii = 5
expected_count = 30
area = size * size * radii - 1  # 327679
rate = area // expected_count  # 10922
```

[image: rate10922_area327679.png]

or

```
size = 256
radii = 8
expected_count = 32
area = size * size * radii - 1  # 524287
rate = area // expected_count  # 16383
```

[image: rate16383_area524287.png].

My guess is due to
[image: enter link description here] .

How to get around it?

-- edit --
Example working parameters.
Added some explanation.
Using `defautl_rng()`
Naming variables `radii` and `expected_count`
Issue with variance
Changed title

Comment: I don't understand what is supposedly "broken" about these results.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what exactly is going wrong a minimum working example that shows the issue.

Comment: This is most definitely not the fault of the random generator

Comment: Compared to a uniform distribution, Poisson *is* stripey. By definition, some values are far more common than others. BUT, what you're doing is wrong to begin with. [The random.poisson docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.poisson.html) warn that you shouldn't use that method. Use a `default_rng` instance instead and reuse it. The reason is that deterministic PRNGs essentially produce the same same sequence of numbers over time, with the seed controlling where you start. That's why you can reproduce a sequence or experiment by specifying the same seed

Comment: When you *don't* specify a seed, PRNGs typically use the CPU's clock. Even with nanosecond precision, this means that several iterations will end up using the same seed. Even if that doesn't happen, using `random.poisson` like this is equivalent to using the same sequence with different starting points. It's quite likely that the starting points will be close together. PRNG algorithms ensure the sequences are as long as possible and there's minimal correlation between values. To get good random values you need to use the same sequence, which means the same PRNG instance

Comment: Have you printed the numbers you generate?  For your second example, the individual numbers hover around 11,000.  You are yielding x, x+x, x+x+x, x+x+x+x, etc.  Then, your Y coordinate is the second byte of that value `(x >> 8) & 256`.  That second 
byte increments at regular intervals.  The stripiness is purely a manifestation of the way you're extracting x, y, and z from a predictable set of numbers.

Comment: In-real life I do use seeded `default_rng`, but I intentionally omitted here, that's not causing issue. I'm just stunned that prng is depleted so easy.

Comment: @axx it's not. It's far more likely that the rest of the code results in rounding, overflow or truncation issues. The question doesn't show how the random numbers are used or converted to coordinates, but if you try to pick bytes for a single random value, you're definitely doing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

I added `print(w)` in the `poisson_point_process`, and added the following at the end.

```
points = list(poisson_point_process(rate,area))
for i in points:
    print(index_to_coordinates(size,i))
```

Here's the output.  It should be crystal clear that you are unrandomizing a random process"

```
11050
10931
10823
10895
10926
11066
10942
10946
11011
11028
11007
10996
10898
10906
10988
10977
11127
11034
10620
10837
10965
10858
10908
10933
10736
11024
10929
10890
10886
10829
(42, 43, 0)
(221, 85, 0)
(36, 128, 0)
(179, 170, 0)
(97, 213, 0)
(155, 0, 1)
(89, 43, 1)
(27, 86, 1)
(30, 129, 1)
(50, 172, 1)
(49, 215, 1)
(37, 2, 2)
(183, 44, 2)
(81, 87, 2)
(61, 130, 2)
(30, 173, 2)
(149, 216, 2)
(175, 3, 3)
(43, 45, 3)
(128, 87, 3)
(85, 130, 3)
(191, 172, 3)
(91, 215, 3)
(16, 2, 4)
(0, 44, 4)
(16, 87, 4)
(193, 129, 4)
(75, 172, 4)
(209, 214, 4)
(30, 1, 5)
```

Comment: I might grt what you are saying: [dividing variable effects variance by square of factor](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cbegin%7Balign*%7D%20%26%5Cmathbf%7BE%7D%28x%5E2-%5Cmathbf%7BE%7D%28x%29%5E2%29%3Drate%5C%5C%20%26y%5Csim%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bsize%7D%5C%5C%20%26%5Cmathbf%7BE%7D%28y%5E2-%5Cmathbf%7BE%7D%28y%29%5E2%29%3D%5Cfrac%7Brate%7D%7Bsize%5E2%7D%5C%5C%20%26z%5Csim%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bsize%5E2%7D%5C%5C%20%26%5Cmathbf%7BE%7D%28z%5E2-%5Cmathbf%7BE%7D%28z%29%5E2%29%3D%5Cfrac%7Brate%7D%7Bsize%5E4%7D%20%5Cend%7Balign*%7D). How to get around it?

Comment: I don't know, because I can't' even guess what you're actually trying to do here.  You're trying to extract 24 bits of information out of a 14-bit random number.  If you want random points in 3D space, then generate 3 random numbers.  Don't try to decompose a summed sequence of smaller numbers.

Comment: That's fine. It was intended as a rhetoric device mainly. And your observation about the size of generated numbers also interesting. I was thinking raising `area` to `size ** 7 * radii (= size * size ** 2 * size * 4 * radii)`, that would raise the length of random number. and changing the mapping to `area = x  + y * size ** 2 + z * size ** 3`. Yet I haven't figured out the reverse mapping completely, nor implemented or tested it, but I'll not miss to give the result if it works.

Comment: Btw, generating 3 random numbers result independent variables. Point process generates variables (crystal clearly) not uncorrelated, even if both expected value and variance have same value for each, therefore covariance is zero. Think trees in a forest, cities...